# SSRS 2008 - text color expression with detail row visibility.hidden

Tags: reporting, ssrs-2008

can I do this:

set font color in expression,

```
=IIF(nameOfTableRow.Visibility.Hidden=true, "Black", "Silver")
```

How can I get value of hidden properties ??

TABLE 
|______________________________|
|______________________________|
|_____________________________|     <---- One Detail Row (visibility-hidden: true/false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of **Report Parameters** to get this done.  Here are the steps.

1. Declare a ReportParameter named "**RowVisibility**" with datatype set as **Boolean**
2. Then from the report designer, select the entire "**Detail**" row and set it's **RowVisibility** to that parameter "[@RowVisibility]" as shown below.
   [image]
3. Then for each individual **Textbox** present inside the **Detail** row.  Set it's **Color** property to your expression string.

=IIF(Parameters!RowVisibility.Value=true, "Black", "Silver")

This would work as you expected.  So based on the report parameter the Tablix RowVisibility will be set and based on the same parameter the Font color also be changed.

Hope this helps.